# Javascript - Determining File Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple file inputs on a page. These are uniquely defined and I cannot use the multiple attribute for this.  When they submit this form the script runs through and checks for a null value on each upload element.

I've created a little status loader that provides some nice visual feedback to the user, and part of what I want to do show them the total upload size.  Unfortunately, what I've written is targeting the DOM element and not the actual file that its referencing.  I've read the API docs and [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) but I'm missing something here.

```
jQuery( "#submit" ).on("click", function(event) {

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        files = [],
        size;

    for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        if( inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == "file" && inputs[i].value != 0 ) {
            files.push(inputs[i].id);       
            }
        }

    for(j=0; j<files.length; j++) {
        size += document.getElementById(files[j]).size;
        }

    console.log(size); //returns NAN

//other stuff
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do: `document.getElementById(files[j]).size`, the `.size` property doesn't exist there.

Try reading from `document.getElementById(files[j]).files` instead.

You can something like: `document.getElementById(files[j]).files[0].size`

I don't think it matters if you have `multiple="multiple"` or not.

Keep in mind that there is a bug in your code. The initial value of `size` is `undefined` and `undefined + 1234` is `NaN` (Not a Number)

Comment: I wasn't aware that `var x; x = x + 3 = NaN`, thanks for that.
Your solution works, but I don't understand this line: `document.getElementById(files[j]).files[0].size` - You select the DOM element and then reference the array again (at its 0 index?..)

Comment: `document.getElementById(files[j])` is DOM node. `document.getElementById(files[j]).files` is a `FileList` that works a bit like an `Array` so you can use `[0]` to find the first `File`. And then you get the `size` property of that file.